# Use of numofreducers in map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

i have a simple doubt in map reduce.

Why we have to set numofreducers in the map reduce driver class.if we do not set,the default value will be 1.if i set 100,100 reduce tasks will run.what is the advantage of that.Is it to reduce the effort of a single node.(if reduce task is 1,the task will be running in 1 node).Is there any other advantages?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Recommend reading this https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces

Answer (score 2):

The right number of reduces seems to be:
`0.95 or 1.75 multiplied by (<no. of nodes> * <no. of maximum containers per node>).`

With 0.95, all of the reduces can launch immediately and start transferring map outputs as the maps finish. With 1.75 the faster nodes will finish their first round of reduces and launch a second wave of reduces doing a much better job of load balancing.

**Increasing the number of reduces increases the framework overhead, but increases load balancing and lowers the cost of failures.**

The scaling factors above are slightly less than whole numbers to reserve a few reduce slots in the framework for speculative-tasks and failed tasks.

So main advantage is load balancing and running tasks in parallel on the cluster.